# Object references and re-assignment problem in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, pointers, reference

Maybe this is a n00bish question, but I'm used to c++'s pointers and references and this is confusing me a bit. Let's say I have the following scenario in a VB.net application:

```
Dim x As New Dictionary(Of String, MyType)
'I add stuff to x
Dim y As MyObject= x("foo1")
'later...
y = New MyType()
'now y and x("foo1") don't point to the same instance anymore
```

The situation is this: I have a collection of objects, and during execution of the program, any of them can be fetched from the collection to be used/edited by another part of the program. Now obviously if I edit the data inside the object it is allright, but what if I want to replace the object,  as I did above at line 5? I would change only the local reference (y) but not the object inside the collection! Is there a way around this? How can I take with me a "reference to the object's reference", instead of just a reference, so if I reassign it it will also reassign the one in the collection? I hope I'm making myself clear, unfortunately english is not my native language, to be clear: in c++ this would be easy using a pointer to a pointer, or passing a pointer to the object always by reference, so calling new or reassignment on it would change the original pointer itself)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use pointers in VB.NET (or C#, except through [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) code).

Instead, to change the original value in the dictionary that you've assigned to `y`, you need to access it again *through the dictionary object itself*, rather than through an excised reference:

```
x("foo1") = New MyType()
```

The reason is that the value at the specified location in the dictionary ("foo1") is assigned to `y`, not a reference to the location itself in the dictionary. I'm not really sure why you're using the `DataObject` class, but `y` will hold a value of type `MyType` when it is assigned in your code. Assigning a new value to `y` will only change the value of `y`, not the original value in the dictionary. It has no knowledge of that value. Think of it essentially as if you're pulling a copy of the value out of the dictionary and placing it in the `y` variable. There's no way to copy a reference to the page in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, got it, it can't be done without access to the dictionary. Thanks!
PS: sorry, the DataObject is a refuse, edited!

Comment: +1. You can make a rough analogy with C++ pointers. You can think of any reference to a reference type as a pointer. So your variable y is like a simple "pointer", and your Dictionary is like a rich data structure that contains a set of "pointers". If you retarget y to "point" to a different object, it doesn't affect the "pointers" in your Dictionary. It sounds like you're used to C++ pointers, so that might be a helpful way to think about it.

Comment: @Mike: yeah, the point is in c++ you can have pointers to pointers, in .net you can't, so what I wanted to do can't be done directly, unless by using wrapper around the original reference, like Heinzi suggested.

Comment: @Master_T: Though I've not been privy to the intricate details of your design, I might humbly suggest that keeping a reference to the dictionary object around whenever you want to modify its contents is a better idea anyway. It makes your code much more readable and your intentions much more explicit. I agree that pointers can be a real handy feature in C/C++, but they can also make it much easier to miss important "side effects" of a section of code, especially when you're trying to understand someone else's.

Answer (score 2):

You would do that in the dictionary itself:

C#:

```
 x["foo1"] = new MyType();
 y = x["foo1"];
```

VB:

```
 x("foo1") = New MyType()
 y = x("foo1")
```

Comment: Mmmm, so it's not possible if I don't have access to the dictionary at the time I call the new()? Is the only solution to bring a reference to the dictionary along? Or is there another way around it?
Also, I'm not sure I understand your code example, what if I add a third line: y = new MyType() ? I don't think that would change replace the item in the collection with the new one... or would it?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the "pointer to pointer" thing (because you don't have access to the dictionary), you need to add a level of indirection to your entries:

```
Class PointerToMyType
    Public Value As MyType
End Class

Dim x As New Dictionary(Of String, PointerToMyType)  

'' add value
x("foo1") = New PointerToMyType() With {.Value = New MyType()}

Dim y As PointerToMyType = x("foo1")  
'' use y.Value

'' later...  
y.Value = New MyType()

'' now y and x("foo1") still point to the same instance
```

Comment: Yep, that woul work, but I decided to just keep a reference to the dictionary with me, more straightforward. Thanks anyway for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if i have got exactly what you are trying to achieve but if i understand correctly, you want the new y object also to be referenced in the X collection.

If that is the case, then this should do it

```
Dim y As DataObject = x("foo1")
'later...
.....
y = New MyType()
//Reassign the new y object to the x collection
x("foo1") = y
.....
```